# How to copy text from browser clipboard using Puppeteer in nodejs

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Is a there a way where I can copy content from browser clipboard using Puppeteer in nodejs. I am trying to copy content post the page is rendered. This is being achieved by the bellow code but unable to get the content.

```
await page.keyboard.down('ControlLeft');
await page.keyboard.press('KeyA');
await page.keyboard.up('ControlLeft');

await page.keyboard.down('ControlLeft');
await page.keyboard.press('KeyC');
await page.keyboard.up('ControlLeft');
```

Answer (score 1):

## Copy from input box

You can evaluate the following snippet to copy data from any input element.

```
function copyText(selector) {
  var copyText = document.querySelector(selector);
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
  return copyText.value;
}
```

Usage:

```
const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
  function copyText(selector) {
    var copyText = document.querySelector(selector);
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    return copyText.value;
  }
  return copyText("#foo");
});
```

now result should contain the text copied from the input box.

## Copy anything into clipboard

You can evaluate the snippet from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46215202/6161265).

```
const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
  function copy(text) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('value', text);
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    input.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(input)
  }
  return copy(document.body.innerHTML); // copy whatever want to copy
});
```

It will create a input element, set your provided text as value and then copy the data from that element, finally remove it after usage.

Comment: I've tried it but `document.execCommand('copy')` returns `false` - it means that this operation doesn't success.

Comment: I get the overall approach. Tried `var copyText = document.body` and `copyText.select()`, - returns copyText.select is not a function.

Comment: @Kushal, document.body.select() shouldn't be a valid function.