# Copying rendered text with Puppeteerjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm having issues finding a way to copy text with [Puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/).

In my research, I've found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49131516/how-to-copy-text-from-browser-clipboard-using-puppeteer-in-nodejs) but, this wasn't what I was trying to do (copy text from input). What I am trying to do is copy text from a website. Then paste it into a Google Doc file. My main goal is to keep the formatting.

I have been able to get the HTML text with:

`let html_content = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerHTML, await page.$('#sites-canvas-main-content > table > tbody > tr > td > div'));`

This unfortunately does not keep the formatted text.

Is this even possible to do with Puppeteer?

Comment: Can you provide what you've attempted for pasting HTML into a google doc? What you may not understand is that the CSS behind the HTML styles it, and that in order to "copy" the styling you need to include that; however it may require that you "apply" the CSS to the html element you are copying so that when you paste it into google docs it has the correct CSS rather than just being HTML without the `style` attribute.  (`<div style="color:black;">` versus `<div>`)

Comment: What I paste the scarped HTML into the Google doc it just uses it as plan text. I'm trying to it to do bold, links, ect. I can get the HTML and the text inside the HTML it just uses it's formatting when being put into the document.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to paste into google docs? :) It would help make your question more complete.

Comment: Absolutely! I'll update that! When it comes to the part that get the HTML I have

Comment: I have ```    for(let link in links)         
    let html_content = await page.evaluate(el => 
    el.innerHTML, await page.$('#sites-canvas-main- 
    content > table > tbody > tr > td > div')) 
    console.log(html_content)} ``` I'm on mobile sorry for any poor formating

Comment: I saw that in your post, no need to put it in the comments. You can also edit your question with the paste code when you get the chance. The first problem/question  I think you should work out is "Can I paste html code with styles into google docs?"

Comment: Okay! I will try that out and report back! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of the solution is to get the calculated styles, using

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/696

```
const button = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const btn = document.querySelector('.button');
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(getComputedStyle(btn)));
});
```

The second part of the solution is to apply those to an element and paste it into google docs...

Comment: Thank for you pointing me in the right direction! I was really lost.

Comment: By the way. I have found this library. [inline-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inline-css)

Comment: I still have not  been able to solve to over all problem. I just pasts the HTML with styles. It doesn't ever change the font size/color of text like the site has. It might just be an issue with google docs.

Comment: Just to let anyone who see's this post in the future. This site was a Google site. I ended up using Google's scripting language to get everything I needed!